# Truncate paragraph after second line Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, truncate

I have a p tag with multi line text,

I want to truncate the para and delete all the texts  after second line

here is how my code looks

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat
</p>
```

Note: I don't understand how can I do this, or is this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: When you say "line," do you mean "line" in the HTML, or "line" in the displayed result (which will vary quite a lot depending on the width of the paragraph on the screen)?

Comment: If the latter, I feel like I've answered a question like this, but I can't find it. Basically you'd progressively put more and more of the text into a `span`, checking [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) each time to see when it goes from being one height to being taller (indicating it's word-wrapped), then do that again until it gets taller again. Then undo your last addition (so it gets shorter again), and keep only the text in the span, deleting the rest.

Comment: line in the displayed result, yes I know it vary quite a lot depending on the width

Answer (score -1):

maybe this page will help you a little bit : 
http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/ 
https://codepen.io/natonischuk/pen/QbGWBa

use css :

```
<style>
  .block {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    max-height: 2.4em;
  }
</style>

<p class="block">.....</p>
```

ratio of (max-height / line-height) is number of line that will be shown (not truncated)